# Could not load shared library symbols for 67 libraries, e.g. libstdc++.so

Tags: android-ndk

I have read so many articles but not to figure out how can I solve this problem:

```
$ /cygdrive/e/adt-bundle-windows-x86/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build

Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver    
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup    
Cygwin         : Generating dependency file converter script    
Compile++ thumb  : Andest1 <= Andest1.cpp    
StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a    
SharedLibrary  : libAndest1.so    
Install        : libAndest1.so => libs/armeabi/libAndest1.so


$ /cygdrive/e/adt-bundle-windows-x86/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-gdb --project=e:/workspace/Andrd1 --port=5000 --start --force --verbose      

0xafd0c52c in epoll_wait () from E:\workspace\Andrd1/./obj/local/armeabi/libc.so    
warning: .dynamic section for "E:\workspace\Andrd1/./obj/local/armeabi/libAndrd1.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 67 libraries, e.g. libstdc++.so.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got this problem too when i debug my native code on eclipse. and finally I found out that we should just ignore it.

> IMPORTANT: The GDB prompt will be preceded by a long list of error
>   messages,
>              where gdb complains that it cannot find various system libraries
>              (e.g. libc.so, libstdc++.so, liblog.so, libcutils.so, etc...)
>
> ```
>        This is normal, because there are no symbol/debug versions of
>        these libraries corresponding to your target device on your
>        development machine. You can safely ignore these messages.
> ```

read the ANDROID-NDK-DOCUMENT and you will find it.

hope i helped.

**EDIT:**

1. that quote can be found in android-ndk-r8d/documentation.html at section NDK-GDB